# Loading static files like CSS and JS to ejs

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express, ejs

I am trying to load some static files to ejs (I was able to load in HTML file but not here in ejs file). Not just static files. **I am not even able to load the CDN files!** Can someone please help me to understand where I am going wrong?
Here is the directory structure:
[image: Directory-structure]

This is my server.js:

```js
const express=require('express');
var app=express();
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient
app.set('view engine', 'ejs')
var path = require('path')
app.use('/static',express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

app.get('/',function(req,res){
 db.collection('testCollection').find().toArray((err, result) => {
    if (err) return console.log(err)
    console.log(result)
    res.render('index.ejs', {testCollection: result})
  })
});
```

This is my index.ejs:

```js
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/main.css"/>
</head>
<body>
<form>
<div id="container"></div>
<ul class="quotes">
 <% for(var i=0; i<testCollection.length; i++) {%>
    <li class="quote">
      <span><%= testCollection[i].name %></span>
    </li>
  <% } %>
</ul>
</form>
</body>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script src="/static/main.js"></script>
</html>
```

In the console I can see only index.ejs file loaded:[image: Console]

Answer (score 4):

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="/main.css"/>`

`<script src="/main.js"></script>`

Above is how you should call your files in index.ejs. You are going to do so because you declare in your `server.js` file 
`app.use('/static',express.static(__dirname + '/public'));`

Comment: The `<link>` tag has no closing slash.

Answer (score 1):

I think that if you add :

```
app.set('views',__dirname);//---> before setting ejs as the View Engine ... (this is for the views folder that you have there but your view is in your current working directory hence __dirname)
var index = require('./index');
app.use('/', index);//---> after declaring static folder...
```

to your code node might know where the files are ...

---

I suggest that you move your `index.ejs` to the views folder and then set:

```
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
```

instead of:

```
app.set('views',__dirname);
```